# Hard/Fast fling using the swipe to dismiss library and a ContentProvider shows the wrong item

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-contentprovider

I have been developing an app that has a listview in which items may be removed by the user.
Now I have been trying to use the swipe to dismiss library in my project, by Roman Nurik: https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss.

I've successfully implemented a button which removes a row (click), however I am unable to use the swipe to dismiss functionality of the library (swipe). This is all because of the canDismiss check I need to do.

I have a cursor (see ContentProvider and LoaderCallbacks) which I was trying to iterate over and use to determine if a row can be dismissed. However this does not seem to work, 'cause when I fling fast/hard it displays the second to last row twice (it's normal position and the last position) and it does the same thing for the first and second rows.

Has anyone ever done something similar? And how did you solve this issue?

My code:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) mAdapter.getItem(position);
if (cursor.getInt(Card.CARD_REMOVABLE_COLUMN_INDEX) == 1) {
    return true;
}
```

But everytime I try to use the cursor, the issue seems to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I guess there is no good solution, other than fetching the required information from the view(s) itself. Unlike with web development, getting the information from the database all the time, is not an option.

I guess you could get the information from the viewtag if you would so desire. I've done something different, using the position I get from the library, I lookup the row in the listview, and check if certain views are visible (every row can be removable, hence they all have the same header(s), I check if a header is visible or not, and handle this).